# How to move nodes along another parallel path in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path

I would like to ask two question about paths
Sorry for my poor English first, and hard to describe my question just in few words in title.
thus I display a schematic diagram below.
[image]
The first one is how to move a node on a line along another parallel path
Actually I know how to generate series of parallel lines with mutiple nodes, and I know that pressing ctrl while moving the nodes can let that node move horizontally or vertically. But I want to do is as the diagram, that is, the node move along the path and make the interval unchanged.

The second question is that, is it possible to make two intersected segment into one path just like the diagram? I could only zoom my file to very large scale and move nodes by mouse, it is hard to find un-parallel with normal scale but this is still a stupid way anyway.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, bg2305沛寶. Have you tried to use [oblique Guide Lines](https://inkscapetutorials.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/working-with-guides-in-inkscape/) and enable [snapping](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html)? Please, tell us about your efforts. Another alternative is drawing horizontal lines and later rotate the whole.

Comment: The guide line seems to be satisfied, it just makes it easy to achieve the goal i want. Thanks for your recommendation!

Comment: Well! Try to solve your problem and once achieved your goal create yourself an answer, if the proposed ones are not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Have Smart Guides and (if you want point snaps) Snap to Point ON, no other snaps.

You can draw a dummy straight line along the wanted route, stretch it to wanted length by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> (=the angle stays) Convert it to guide by applying View > Guides > Make Guide. Actually a guide is not a must, the dummy line does the same, but it can cause harms if the drawing is dense and you cannot access it. Guides can be removed separately.

Drag along the guide. The same works with your 2<sup>nd</sup> case. The lines itself do the job of the guides because only shortening is needed. Here you want also snap to point! Join the shortened lines with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> if needed.